# How to optimize and improve a charting macro for MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

This macro searches for all instances of 4 words in a table in the document. I limited the range by citing "ActiveDocument.Tables(3) also known as the third table in the document.

I wanted to know:
(1) if there was an easier way to write my 4 while loops to have them look and record the values for 4 separate instances of a word.
 (2) If there's a syntactical way to limit the range of the code on the third column of the third table in the document.

The reason I had the while loops, is to record 4 distinct values for 4 distinct words into an Excel document for charting reasons http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629397.aspx

Here's my code so far:

```
Sub CreateChartFromExistingTable()

    Dim salesChart As Chart
    Dim chartWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim range As range
    Dim List
    Dim jCount As Integer
    Dim range1 As range
    Dim kCount As Integer
    Dim range2 As range
    Dim lCount As Integer
    Dim range3 As range


    Set salesChart = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    Set chartWorkSheet = salesChart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)

    Set range = ActiveDocument.Tables(3).range
    Set range1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(3).range
    Set range2 = ActiveDocument.Tables(3).range
    Set range3 = ActiveDocument.Tables(3).range
    iCount = 0

    With range.Find
    .Text = "Passed"
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
            iCount = iCount + 1
        Loop

    End With

    jCount = 0
    With range1.Find
    .Text = "Failed"
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
            jCount = jCount + 1
        Loop

    End With
    kCount = 0
    With range2.Find
    .Text = "No Run"
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
            kCount = kCount + 1
        Loop

    End With
    lCount = 0
    With range3.Find
    .Text = "N/A"
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
            lCount = lCount + 1
        Loop

    End With

    chartWorkSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize chartWorkSheet.range("A1:B5")
    chartWorkSheet.range("Table1[[#Headers],[Series 1]]").FormulaR1C1 = "Test Instances Summary Graph"

    chartWorkSheet.range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "Passed"
    chartWorkSheet.range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "Failed"
    chartWorkSheet.range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "No Run"
    chartWorkSheet.range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = "N/A"
    chartWorkSheet.range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = iCount
    chartWorkSheet.range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = jCount
    chartWorkSheet.range("B4").FormulaR1C1 = kCount
    chartWorkSheet.range("B5").FormulaR1C1 = lCount

    salesChart.ChartType = xlPie
    salesChart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Please make sure you have Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library referenced in your VB editor in MS Word.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

```
Dim Range As Range
Dim maxCases, curCase, iCount, jCount, kCount, lCount As Integer
Dim texts(5) As String

texts(1) = "Passed"
texts(2) = "Failed"
texts(3) = "No Run"
texts(4) = "N/A"

maxCases = 4
curCase = 0
Do
    curCase = curCase + 1
    curCount = 0

    ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Range.Columns(3).Select
    Set Range = Selection.Range
    With Range.Find
        .Text = texts(curCase)
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
            curCount = curCount + 1
        Loop

        If (curCase = 1) Then
            iCount = curCount
        ElseIf (curCase = 2) Then
            jCount = curCount
        ElseIf (curCase = 3) Then
            kCount = curCount
        ElseIf (curCase = 4) Then
            lCount = curCount
        End If

    End With

Loop While (curCase < maxCases)
```

I have tested it and the  `Set Range =` part has to be inside the loop; otherwise it would work just for the first iteration.